# How can I display count of imagefield images in views?

Tags: facebook, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I want to display the number of images uploaded to an imagefield, in a views field or views tpl.php. How can I do this? My imagefield is called boatimages. I tried this but it comes out as 0, not the correct number: < ? php print count($fields->field_boatimages) ?>

Answer (score 0):

Ack. I do not think count() works like that.

Why not just do this using Views? Take a look at Arguments > Settings and you'll see 'display record count' which seems like all you would need for this.

Comment: I don't understand. There is no "Settings" for "Arguments" in a view? And theres no argument called "display record count" in Arguments?

Comment: Yes, it's not obvious at all if you don't know how this works. In your new view select boatimages for the field. Then set your argument to the same field. For action to take if argument not present, choose summary sorted. Now you should see the setting that wasn't there before-- display record count.

Comment: (The "Settings" link is the gear icon.)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is install the devel module and use the function dpm to print the variable if you wanna know the structure (print_r() may work too). If count isn't working it's because, you are probably using it with the wrong data.

OR, you could just query the database for the field. I'm gonna provide you instructions for drupal 7 but drupal 6 should be similar.

Check the table field_data_field_boatimages. See how there's a list of your images related with a single entity_id

Then execute this query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `field_data_field_boatimages` WHERE entity_id = ###
```

Where ### is the entity_id you want to know. You can get it by looking for arg(1) if arg(0) == node in your page.

Now you just have to use php power to print thar result

```
$query = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `field_data_field_boatimages` WHERE entity_id = :eid
$result = db_query($query, array(':eid', $nid))->fetchField();
echo $result;
```

Drupal 6 would be very similar. Just a little difference in the table names and the query syntax. For example using db_result instead of fetchField()

Anyway good luck!

Comment: Doing it in this manner seems like a good learning exercise, but also  a trip around the horn, since you can accomplish this with a view in a hot minute. Also, he still has to adapt the D7 example for D6.